# PhpStorm doesn't recognize KernelBrowser getResponse functions

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, code-completion

I'm working on a Symfony project and due to most stuff working better in PhpStorm, I decided to move over to using PhpStorm.

If I'm writing PHPUnit tests, I use the following code a bunch of times:

```
$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
```

This is to test whether a route exists. However, PhpStorm gives the following error when hovering over `isSuccessful()`:

```
Method 'isSuccessful() not found in \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Response
```

And when I use `$client->getResponse()->` I get no quick select popup to select a method from.

I've tried adding the packages from Symfony that contains the code from `$client` and `getResponse()` to the External Libraries with PHP Include Path, like this:

[image: PHP include path]

However, this still doesn't solve it (this is what I had to do for PHPUnit to make `assertTrue` appear in the quick select when using `$this->`

How do I make this work correctly? I have the Symfony plugin enabled.

Comment: Not a Symfony user here (more Laravel one) .. but I see `Symfony\Component\**HttpFoundation**\Response` class and not `Symfony\Component\**HttpKernel**\Response`. Could be wrong class resolution by IDE (`Response`) or bad PHPDoc signature...

Comment: `$client` is of type `KernelBrowser`, which extends `Client` from `framework-bundle`, which extends `HttpKernelBrowser`. That class contains the PHPDoc ` * @method Response getResponse() A Response instance` (this `Response` has no typing apparently) and the class extends `Client` from `http-kernel`. That contains the same `@method` (which is from type `HttpFoundation/Response`, and the class extends `AbstractBrowser`, which extends from `Client` in `browser-kit` which contains the real `getResponse` method. Sorry for the hard explaination but AFAIK it doesn't use the `HttpKernel/Response`.

Comment: For me it works OK even in Laravel app. Code is (will not execute as needs proper params for constructor, but shows how it works in IDE): `$client = new HttpKernelBrowser(null); $client->getResponse()->isSuccessful();` -- no warnings for `isSuccessful()` as `getResponse()` correctly detected as returning instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`.

Comment: However, I use the following to create my `$client` (should've mentioned): `$client = $this->createClient();` which returns `KernelBrowser` instead of `HttpKernelBrowser`. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: So right now I may suggest: 1) try `File | Invalidate caches` and restart IDE; 2) Place caret on `getResponse` in `$client->getResponse()->` line and see what type it is (Ctrl+Q or "View | Quick Documentation"). Based on your initial message it resolves to the wrong class/namespace...

Comment: *"which returns KernelBrowser instead of HttpKernelBrowser"* -- Sadly I do not have KernelBrowser class in my codebase (must be an additional composer package).. so not sure about it.

Comment: Thanks, the `File | Invalidate caches` did work, though I'm not sure what actually fixed the problem entirely.

Comment: If you can create a blank project (with all dependencies) that would illustrate the issue that I can download and try on my computer, I can have a deeper look at what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198183/discussion-between-joshua-bakker-and-lazyone).

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I think the reason why it didn't work at first was because I didn't create the project but instead cloned a project from our server.

With a new project, it worked how it should. With my cloned project, I had to click `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` in the `File` menu. This fixed the problem.

(thanks to LazyOne for telling me to try the `Invalidate Caches` thing).

--

According to LazyOne it doesn't matter it's a cloned repo. It's mostly just a  project with corrupt indexes/caches. `Invalidate Caches` fixed the bug.

Comment: TBH the way how you get your source code should make no difference .. as IDE keeps indexes separate for each project (for project code; based on file path AFAIK). So it must be something else that caused this (e.g. caches/indexes corruption; some plugins can introduce such issues, e.g. .gitignore plugin did it quite few times in the past). In any case: "Invalidate Caches" is the usual suggestion when something suddenly stopped working / code analysis shows unexpected things. Glad it helped.